# I want to display two text fields side by side inside signup form box in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to display two text fields side by side in rails .slim files,

I'm using `.fields` and signup box and `form_for` and I don't know how can I display those on same line:

Here is what I'm doing:

```
 = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name),builder: Bulma::FormBuilder) do |f|
            .field
              .control
                = f.text_field :username,:style => "width:230px;", placeholder: "Enter Username", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'username', class: 'input',label: "Username"
            br
            .field
              .control
                = f.email_field :email, :style => "width:230px;", placeholder: "Enter E-Mail", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'email', class: 'input',label: "E-Mail"
            br
            .field
              .control
                = f.password_field :password, :style => "width:230px;", placeholder: "Enter Password", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'password', class: 'input',label: "Password"
            br
            .field
              .control
                = f.password_field :confirm_password, :style => "width:230px;", placeholder: "Confirm Password", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'confirm_password', class: 'input',label: "Confrirm Password"
```

I want something like this:

```
Username:-----------------      E-mail:---------------------

passowrd:-----------------      confirm Password:------------------
```

Comment: Anybody can guide me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Put the 2 fields in the same box and remove the br tag.

```rb
 = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name),builder: Bulma::FormBuilder) do |f|
  .field
    .control
      = f.text_field :username,:style => "width:230px;", placeholder: "Enter Username", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'username', class: 'input',label: "Username"
      = f.email_field :email, :style => "width:230px;", placeholder: "Enter E-Mail", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'email', class: 'input',label: "E-Mail"
   br
   .field
     .control
       = f.password_field :password, :style => "width:230px;", placeholder: "Enter Password", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'password', class: 'input',label: "Password"
       = f.password_field :confirm_password, :style => "width:230px;", placeholder: "Confirm Password", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'confirm_password', class: 'input',label: "Confrirm Password"
```

Comment: can you suggest something else?

Comment: If you use bootstrap you could add .d-flex class to the .control div else you could add display: flex in the css to the .control class.

Comment: will explain a little more? should i show you my css?

Comment: How does your css file looks?